# HttpErrorResponse "Http failure response for http://localhost:8443/gestion-centros-api/workCenters/vehicles: 500 OK"

Tags: angular

I'm unable to retrieve the list of vehicles from the api. That was the error showed. I need help.

Below is my code

**Logic from the service**

```
  getAllVehicle(): Observable<Vehicles[]> {
return this.http.get<Vehicles[]>( this.getApiBaseUrl() + '/workCenters/vehicles');
```

}

**Logic from vehicle.ts**

```
getAllVehicles() {
this.vehicles = [];
this.workCenterFilterService.getAllVehicle().subscribe(
  response => {
  console.log(response);
    this.vehicles = response;
}, error1 => {
  console.log(error1);

});
```

}

Comment: backend API is not working properly. Code Status 500 told it.

Answer (score 0):

You could debug your API http://localhost:8443/gestion-centros-api/workCenters/vehicles with Postman.
-> https://www.postman.com/

Error 500 always means, that something went wrong on the Server and you have to look in the logs to find out the issue.